BPTT in multi-layer RNN
I am trying to understand the Backpropagation through time algorithm for multi-layer RNNs but I'm facing challenges in extending the process from single-layer to multi-layer architectures.
I have derived the gradients of BPTT for RNNs with a single hidden layer, following the approach outlined in Goodfellow's Deep Learning Book (https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/rnn.html Chapter 10, page 378):
Forward Propagation
\begin{align}
    h_t &= \phi \left(Wx_t+W_rh_{t-1}+b^1\right) &&\in \mathbb{R}^{n_1}\qquad\text{und}\label{eqRNNFP1}\\
    o_t & = W^2h_t+b^{2} &&\in \mathbb{R}^{n_2} \label{eqRNNFP2},
\end{align}
with $W\in\mathbb{R}^{n_1\times n_0}, W_r \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1\times n_1}$ and $W^2\in \mathbb{R}^{n_2\times n_1}$ and
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{cost} &= \frac{1}{T} \sum\limits_{t=1}^T \mathrm{cost}_t(\hat{y}_t,y_t) 
\end{align}
Gradients for BPTT
$1\leq i \leq n^l$ is the $i$th neuron of layer $l$ with $0\leq l\leq 2$, $h_t$ is the hidden state at time step $t$ and $o_t$ is the net's Output at time step $t$. $\phi$ is the activation function, $\mathrm{cost}$ a loss function. $H_{t,D}$ is a diagonal matrix with the entry $1-((h_t)_i)^2$ in row/column $i$, $1\leq i \leq n_1$.
Then we get
\begin{align}
    \nabla_{b^1}\mathrm{cost} &=\sum\limits_{t=1}^{T}\left(\frac{\partial\, h_t}{\partial\, b^1}\right)^\top \nabla_{h_t} \mathrm{cost}_t \label{eqb1} \\ 
    \nabla_{b^2}\mathrm{cost}  &= \sum\limits_{t=1}^{T}\nabla_{o_t} \mathrm{cost}_t \label{eqb2}\\
    \nabla_{W}\mathrm{cost} &= \sum\limits^T_{t=1}\sum\limits_i\left(\frac{\partial\mathrm{cost}_t}{\partial h_{t,i}} \right) x_t^\top \label{eqW}\\
    \nabla_{W^2}\mathrm{cost} &= \sum\limits_{t=1}^{T}(\nabla_{o_t} \mathrm{cost})\, h_t^\top \label{eqWL}\\
    \nabla_{W_r}\mathrm{cost} &= \sum\limits^T_{t=1}\sum\limits_i\left(\frac{\partial\mathrm{cost}_t}{\partial h_{t,i}} \right) h_{t-1}^\top \label{eqWr}
\end{align}
Using the hyperbolic tangent as activation, we obtain:
\begin{align}
    \nabla_{b^1}\mathrm{cost} &= \sum\limits_{t=1}^{T} H_{t,D}\, \nabla_{h_t} \mathrm{cost}_t \label{eqb1t} \\ 
    \nabla_{W}\mathrm{cost} & {=}\sum\limits^T_{t=1} H_{t,D}\, (\nabla_{h_t} \mathrm{cost}_t)\, x_t^\top  \label{eqWt}\\
    \nabla_{W_r}\mathrm{cost} &{=}\sum\limits^T_{t=1} H_{t,D}\, (\nabla_{h_t} \mathrm{cost}_t)\, h_{t-1}^\top \label{eqWrt}\\
    \nabla_{h_t} \mathrm{cost}&{=}W_r^\top\, H_{t+1,D}\,( \nabla_{h_{t+1}}\mathrm{cost})+(W^2)^\top (\nabla_{o_t} \mathrm{cost})         \label{eqht}  
\end{align}
For cross-entropy-loss and softmax applied to the output layer, we have:
\begin{align}
        (\nabla_{o_t} \mathrm{cost})_i&{=} \hat{y}_{t,i} - y_{t,i}. \label{eqot}
\end{align}
Proof
Using the chain rule and the aforementioned conditions, we have:
\begin{align}
    (\nabla_{o_t} \mathrm{cost})_i=\frac{\partial \mathrm{cost}}{\partial (o_t)_i} = \frac{\partial \mathrm{cost}}{\partial \mathrm{cost}_t} \, \frac{\partial \mathrm{cost}_t}{\partial (o_t)_i}=\hat{y}_{t,i} - y_{t,i}
\end{align}
due to $\hat{y}t = \mathrm{softmax}(o_t)$. At time step $t=T$, we get:
\begin{align}
    \nabla_{h_T} \mathrm{cost} = (W^2)^\top \nabla_{o_T} \mathrm{cost}. \label{Nablah}
\end{align}
Iterating backwards from $t=T-1$ to $t=1$, we obtain:
\begin{align}
    \nabla_{h_t} \mathrm{cost} &= \left( \frac{\partial h_{t+1}}{\partial h_t}\right)^\top \nabla_{h_{t+1}} \mathrm{cost} + \left( \frac{\partial o_t}{\partial h_t}\right)^\top \, (\nabla_{o_t} \mathrm{cost})\\
    &= W_r^\top\, H_{t+1,D}\,( \nabla_{h_{t+1}}\mathrm{cost})+(W^2)^\top (\nabla_{o_t} \mathrm{cost}).
\end{align}
Using the chain rule, we find:
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial \mathrm{cost}}{\partial b^1_i} =  \frac{\partial \mathrm{cost}}{\partial h_t} \, \frac{\partial h_t}{\partial b^1_i}, 
\end{align}
and, due to $\tanh'(x) = 1- x^2$, the second part. All other gradients follow similarly.
Question How can I generalize the gradients of BPTT for RNNs with multiple hidden layers?
My idea is that maybe
\begin{align}
    \nabla_{h^l_t} \mathrm{cost} = \left( \frac{\partial h^l_{t+1}}{\partial h^l_t}\right)^\top \nabla_{h^l_{t+1}} \mathrm{cost} + \left( \frac{\partial o_t}{\partial h^l_t}\right)^\top \, (\nabla_{o_t} \mathrm{cost}) + \left( \frac{\partial h^{l+1}_{t}}{\partial h^l_t}\right)^\top \nabla_{h^{l+1}_{t}} \mathrm{cost}
\end{align}
However, I'm uncertain and would appreciate some guidance. Additionally, I believe that the rest of the gradients (i.e., $\nabla{W^l}\mathrm{cost}$) might require additional terms, but I'm unsure how to proceed.
Any advice or guidance is greatly appreciated!
(English isn't my first language, so I apologize if there are any errors or if my explanation is unclear.)
